# Wordpress hide subcategories and categories when post is missing custom field value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to only show the category and subcategory when the post's custom field is not empty. As of right now it does show the category and subcategory but then it is just an empty space below the subcategory. (because the custom field is and should be empty).

```
<?php function ow_categories_with_subcategories_and_posts( $taxonomy, $post_type ) {

    // Get the top categories that belong to the provided taxonomy (the ones without parent)
    $categories = get_terms( 
        array(
            'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
            'parent'     => 0,
            'orderby'    => 'term_id',
            'hide_empty' => true

        )
    );
    ?>
<div class="accordions-container">
    <?php
        // Iterate through all categories to display each individual category
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

            $cat_name = $category->name;
            $cat_id   = $category->term_id;
            $cat_slug = $category->slug;

            ?>
    <div class="accordion-wrapper">
        <?php
            // Display the name of each individual category
            echo '<h2><i class="fa-regular fa-lightbulb-on"></i> ' . $cat_name . '</h3>'; 


            // Get all the subcategories that belong to the current category
            $subcategories = get_terms(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
                    'parent'     => $cat_id, // <-- The parent is the current category
                    'orderby'    => 'term_id',
                    'hide_empty' => true
                )
            );
            ?>
        <div class="subcategory-wrapper">
            <?php
                // Iterate through all subcategories to display each individual subcategory
                foreach ( $subcategories as $subcategory ) {

                    $subcat_name = $subcategory->name;
                    $subcat_id   = $subcategory->term_id;
                    $subcat_slug = $subcategory->slug;
        
                    
                    
                    
                    $child_subcategories = get_terms(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
                    'parent'     => $subcat_id, // <-- The parent is the current category
                    'orderby'    => 'term_id',
                    'hide_empty' => true
                )
            );

                    
                        
// Display the name of each individual subcategory with ID and Slug
                    echo '<button class="accordion">' . $subcat_name . '</button>';
                    echo '<div class="panel">';
?>
            <div>
                <?php
                    foreach ( $child_subcategories as $child_subcategory ) {

                    $child_subcat_name = $child_subcategory->name;
                    $child_subcat_id   = $child_subcategory->term_id;
                    $child_subcat_slug = $child_subcategory->slug;
                        
                        ?>
                <h4 class="accordian-child-subcategory"><?php echo $child_subcat_name ?></h4>

                <?php

                    // Get all posts that belong to this specific subcategory
                    $posts = new WP_Query(
                        array(
                            'post_type'      => $post_type,
                            'posts_per_page' => -1, // <-- Show all posts
                            'hide_empty'     => true,
                            'order'          => 'ASC',
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'specification_sheet',
                                    'value'   => '', 
                                    'compare' => '!='
                                )
                            ),
                            'tax_query'      => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                    'terms'    => $child_subcat_id,
                                    'field'    => 'id'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );
                        
                        
                        
                        // If there are posts available within this subcategory
                    if ( $posts->have_posts() ){

                            // As long as there are posts to show
                            while ( $posts->have_posts() ): $posts->the_post();

                                //Show the title of each post with the Post ID
                                ?>
                <div class="post-loop-single">
                    <div class="post-loop-text">
                        <div class="post-loop-title">
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?><?php if( get_field('discontinued')) {
                ?> - Discontinued<?php } else if(get_field('phasing_out')) { 
                ?> - Phasing Out<?php } ?></h3>
                            <div class="post-loop-spec-sheet"><a href="<?php the_field('specification_sheet'); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa-light fa-file-magnifying-glass"></i> Specification Sheet</a></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php

                            endwhile;
                            ?>

                <?php
                    
                    } else {
                        
                    }
                    
                    wp_reset_query();
                }
                
            
                    ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo '</div>'; 
                }
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
            
        }
        ?>
</div>
<?php

}
ow_categories_with_subcategories_and_posts( 'product-document-category', 'product-document' );
?>
```

This is an example of what a correct category -> subcategory -> post with not empty custom field looks like

[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc8jR.png)

This is an example of what an incorrect category -> subcategory -> post with empty custom field looks like

[incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K013v.png)

The goal is to have the incorrect category not show up at all.

I have tried many things. I have rearranged, attempted different get_terms functionalities, and none have proven to work so far.

Comment: _"when the post's custom field is not empty"_ - you are saying post, singular, here - but your first screenshot already appears to show more than just _one_ post below the category, so how is that supposed to fit together? Please clarify, whether you want this based on just one single post, or if _all_ posts in a (sub-)category are supposed to fulfill / not fulfill the condition at the same time.

Comment: Either way, the problem appears to be, that you already output the category header, _before_ you even checked on the posts in that category. You will have to fetch and check on the post(s), before you do that.

Comment: @CBroe That is correct! I output the category header before I checked on the posts in that category. This is what I am not sure how to do. I have done a lot of research and attempts at grabbing the custom field value for the post before looping through everything, but have not found a solution

Comment: Basically, you just need to change the order in which you output, and fetch data. Instead of outputting the category name first, then fetching the posts and outputting those - fetch the posts first, and output the category name _and_ loop over the posts, only if you have posts.